# Unknown number x, 45•G.C.F(125, x) = L.C.M (125, x)

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization, least-common-multiple

The least common multiple  of 125 and an unknown number x  is 45 times their  greatest common divisor. Here is what I've tried:

Let $\gcd(125,x) = G$ and $\mathrm{lcm}(125,x)=L$.

We know
$$
125 \times x = G \times L \ \text{ and } L = 45G
  \implies 125x = 45G^2
  \implies \frac{25}{9}x = G^2.
$$

Because  $G$ is an integer, so  are $x$ and $G^2$, so $9|x$.

We know $125\times x = 45G^2$. The two numbers are not relatively prime, because $G \ne 1$.  So the number we are looking for should at least be divisible by $5$, and hence by $45$. By trying out multiples of $45$, I get the answer as 225.

Is there a way to eliminate the numbers closer ?  Even this might be easy because 125 has 3 factors but it is long way for numbers with many factors like 360. Is any other way to solve but also shorter ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have the solution of $$x= 45\times 125$$

Note that in this case $L=45\times 125$ and $G=125$ thus $L=45G$

In general If $G(x,y)=d$, then $x=md$ and $y=nd$ where $G(m,n)=1.$

Using this fact may help reduce calculations in more complicated cases.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your argument that $9 \mid x$, you know that $125 \mid L$, requiring $125 \mid 45 G$, so $25 \mid 9 G$, forcing $25 \mid G$.  But this means $25 \mid 125$ and $25 \mid x$.  Then we know $9 \mid x$ and $25 \mid x$, so $225 \mid x$.